# How can i force Jsoup to start parsing after a specific line, thereby ignoring redundant information?

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse HTML pages all of which have same structure and contain redundant information at the starting of the page, say about the first 2000 lines of the HTML document. Is there any way to forcing Jsoup it to start parsing after a specific line ? Will this have significant affect on the speed of my code ?

Comment: Jsoup uses a parse tree, but it's intended to be very resilient. Maybe you could try manually removing the first 2000 lines, then running Jsoup on the remaining nodes, and see if it is able to make a reasonable parse tree. I don't know if this optimization will make a big difference; Jsoup is already insanely fast.